# ALM QC Test Coverage Progress Report

Tags: testing, report, alm, hp-quality-center, test-coverage

I have been handed over responsibility of improving the current reporting structure of a project on ALM QC. What is the best way for me to produce a graph/report showing planned vs actual vs actual passed?

Ideally this would be directly via QC rather than querybuilder and then excel. The test cases had not been linked with Releases/Cycles which I have now done, however the coverage progress graph is not pulling the data so I wonder if I am missing a step?

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you